# Options menu won't show in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, menu

I have a Google Nexus 7 tablet, which runs Android 4.1.1, and I can't seem to get my app to display the little "three tiny squares in a vertical line" symbol on the lower right indicating that there's an options menu available. My build, targeted at 2.3.3, will display an options menu on other devices (a 2.3.3 phone and a 4.0.3 phone), but not on the Nexus 7. To illustrate the problem, I used Eclipse to build both a bare-bones "Hello World", which comes with a single option menu item, 'Settings', and also built the BluetoothChat example from the Android-10 SDKs. The barebones one doesn't have the menu symbol, while the BluetoothChat does. Looking at the code for each, I can't see a difference in how the menus are handled as far as construction and inflation, so I'm hoping somebody has some ideas. Good menu icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPDXy.jpg  No menu icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulXPd.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the problem. In the manifest I had

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Changing that to

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

fixed the problem and now the menu button on the ActionBar appears. The BluetoothChat sample worked because its manifest omitted the targetSdkVerion:

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
```

Comment: on my nexus 7 the menu is displayed at the top of the screen. Is it possible to display it at the bottom of the screen? like in you screenshot http://i.imgur.com/31Wop.jpg

Comment: @Charles: I presume that the positioning of the menu icon is decided somehow by the OS. In my app, it just automatically appears at the bottom of the Nexus 7 screen. Have you created an app where it appears at the top?

Comment: I actually inverted android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion. It's ok now thanks :)

Comment: I had to set target=android-11 in project.properties to get this to work. Setting it to 10 would not work.

Answer (score 0):

From what my test shows, you can stick with both minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion even if there not the same. As long as the Project Build Target (define in the project properties) have the same value as the minSdkVersion. For me, I want to have the old menu in the 2.2 versions but the new one (in the title bar) for 3.0 and higher.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

In project properties :

```
# Project target.
target=android-8
```

It seems to work by showing the old option menu at the bottom (or with the Menu button) on my 2.2 and 2.3 virtual devices and showing the new one on my 3.0, 4.0 and 4.2 virtual and physical devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be true for the Nexus 7. An application of mine has the same problem described above, and using the exact options you described does not solve it. However, the solution given by @JohnJorsett does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this fro android 4.0 and up for showing options menu
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);